# Install a nuget package to a folder without a csproj

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget, csproj

Assuming I have packaged a .net application e.g. `MyConsoleApp.nupkg` and have it available in a source, how would I go about "installing" this to a folder, such that I can run it from this folder:

```
my-folder/MyConsoleApp.dll
my-folder/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
....Other references....
```

I have tried nuget install with packagesDirectory option, but this gives the familiar output in the packages folder e.g:

```
myconsoleapp/1.0.0/lib/netcoreapp3.1/MyConsoleApp.dll
newtonsoft.json/11.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
newtonsoft.json/11.0.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
newtonsoft.json/11.0.1/lib/net20/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
....Other references....
```

I imagine there is a msbuild target which copies the correct content out of the packages directory to a build directory - is there an easy way to use this?

I have tried using `dotnet restore/build` with variations of a `.proj` file using PackageReference which make no reference to a specific build target, but these have not worked:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="MyConsoleApp" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Project>
```

I don't want to make a MyDummy.csproj which references my console app (or asp.net core app) to achieve this because it doesn't seem very clean, and I'm worried about getting the SDK and `<PropertyGroup>` stuff compatibly correct.

I understand this may not fall under best practices, but I would like to see if it can be done in any case.

#### Background

I want to deploy a mesh of c# core libraries, applications and plugins such that they all use the exact same versions.

The libraries (core application framework) are referenced by the applications (web apis, background service workers) and by the plugins (dotnet-script with nuget references to the libraries).  The plugins are in turn invoked by the libraries.

The plugins must reference the same library assemblies as loaded by the applications, yet are resolved as NuGet references at runtime, which avoids a long list of guessed references to System.Etc.Dll in the scripts and related runtime failures.

Installing the applications via nuget packages leads to an interesting way to get a single source of truth for all - the nuget source.

Comment: Can you share *why* you want to do this? There may be a better way of achieving what you want.

Comment: Updated question - although I am aware of many ways of achieving what I want.  The question is really around the mechanics of the msbuild nuget resolve that is used during the build target.  Consider it academic if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen how dotnet-script manages to do it:

https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script/blob/master/src/Dotnet.Script.DependencyModel/ProjectSystem/csproj.template

During the msbuild of a project that has packagereferences, you are able to get access to the list of references.  This is similar to doing a full build of a dummy project, but looks likely the only way to do this as of now - nobody seems to want to answer so I'll leave this here!